# Spring Data - OR condition in a repository method name

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Data project I have a following entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.CardPair", attributeNodes = {})
@Table(name = "card_pairs")
public class CardPair extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7571004010972840728L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "card_pairs_id_seq", sequenceName = "card_pairs_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "card_pairs_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card1_id")
    private Card card1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card2_id")
    private Card card2;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "selected_card_id")
    private Card selectedCard;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
    private Board board;

....

}
```

I need to implement a Spring Data repository method that will look for a `CardPair` based on `cardPairId`, `board` and `card`. The more complicated case to me is a `Card` because I need to construct a condition where `card1 = card or card2 = card`

Is it possible to provide this condition via Spring Data repository method name ?

For example

```
cardPairRepository.findByIdAndBoardAnd[card1 = card or card2 = card]AndSelectedCardIsNull(cardPairId, board, card);
```

Is it possible to translate this condition `card1 = card or card2 = card` in a method name ?

Comment: Are you just looking for a method name here?

Comment: Yes, I can't construct this method name with a mentioned condition

Comment: Use the finder methods only for simple use cases, for complexer cases write a query and use the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to write the query yourself using HPQL..

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented JPQL query and now everything works fine. `@Query(value = "SELECT cp FROM CardPair cp WHERE id = :cardPairId AND board = :board AND card1 = :card OR card2 = :card AND selectedCard is null")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve this using just method name since you need the last condition to be in parentheses: `id = ? AND board = ? AND (card1 = ? OR card2 = ?)`. There is no way to infer this from method name since it is intended to cover basic cases only.

There are three ways in your case:

- @Query annotation (the best candidate for you) http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query
- Named queries http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries
- Specifications http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Answer (score 0):

You can find all operations here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html section 2.2.2

```
findByIdAndBoardAndCard1OrCard2(cardPairId, board, card, card);
```

I haven't testen the order of this, but it should be something like this

Comment: it doesn't work - findByIdAndBoardAndCard1OrCard2(cardPairId, currentBoard, card) with run-time exception.

Comment: card needs to be in the parameters twice.

Comment: Besides my last comment, it might not work at all due to brackets that should be added to the OR statement. But it might be that spring knows how to handle this due to order. the `@Query` suggest by Alec is probably safer.