# Need to write Spring Data JPA interface method for Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

How can i convert the following native into Spring Data JPA interface method :

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = " select count(*) from TABLE "
                    + "where ( ColumOne =:xyz  or ColumnTwo =:xyz ) "
                    + "and STATUS_TX in ('On Hold')")
    int countAllByStatusAndName(@Param("xyz") String xyx);
```

I have written as

`Long countByStatusTXAndColumnOnOrColumnTwo (String status, String xyz)` . But its not working

I specifically need that or condition between ColumnOne and ColumnTwo.

Comment: where is your entity class ?

Comment: Pick a **good** method name, and annotate the method with `@Query`, with the appropriate JPQL query as value.

Comment: My Methodis working written in native query ....I want to write a corresponding JPA speicific interface method for that . Please guide me

Comment: @IshantGaurav JPA Query by Method Name purely works based on Entity Variable Names. Please post your Entity Structure

Comment: As per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115582/spring-data-or-condition-in-a-repository-method-name. It seems like what i want to achieve using Spring Data JPA is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in the method name. `ColumnOn` instead of `ColumnOne`. Try `Long countByStatusTXAndColumnOneOrColumnTwo (String status, String xyz)`